# Is the youth price applicable to foreigners for air travel in Scandinavia?

Tags: tickets, airlines, sweden, norway

I'm Brazilian and I'm planning to visit Norway and Sweden. I'm planning on making the internal trips through Wideroe and I noticed the prices for youths (12-25 years old) are cheaper.

Since I will still be 24, I wonder if this kind of discount is applicable to foreigners like me or if there are some other special conditions, since I don't want to have a surprise at the airport.

Googling or searching the official website about it doesn't have much information on the topic.

Comment: I can't speak to this specific airline, but I've used other European airlines' youth fares before despite not being a European.  Hopefully you'll be able to as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Widerøe Ticket types](http://www.wideroe.no/en/tickets/ticket-types), there is no restriction on the nationality of the customer:

> **Rules for the Youth-ticket**
>
> - Valid for Youth under 26
> - Valid for Widerøe and SAS flights within Scandinavia only, and Widerøe flights to/from the UK
> - Not valid for children between 5-12 years of age travelling alone (UM)
> - A reservation is confirmed when you get a booking reference on the screen or by e-mail
> - A valid ID has to be shown on request before boarding the flight
> - Only electronic tickets apply (e-ticket)
> - No refund apart from when using the 24 hour cancellation rights.
> - You may change your ticket for a fee of NOK 300 per person per flight (each way) (DKK 400 from DK, SEK 500 from SE). You may change your flight upto 1 hour prior to your departure.
> - You may only change your tickets within the same pricerange as your purchased tickets and between the same destinations.
> - Tickets for youth has to be booked separately. You will need to make a separate booking for adults or children travelling together with a youth.
> - When booking a youth and baby (under 2 years): Book your youth ticket first and use the "Note to wideroe.no" on the payment page to tell us that you are travelling with a baby (under 2 years).
> - Limited number of seats available per flight

Comment: This seems the right answer. I actually purchased the youth ticket, in the purchasing process there is another text saying practically the same, it also mentions that they may ask to verify your age, but mentions nothing about the nationality of the passenger.